# Beamer mini frame navigation bullet color

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

In the example below, the color of the navigation bullets seems to be uncontrollable. The active section should be in red while the unactive sections should be in blue (with empty bullets). As you can see on the top right of the slide, while I would like the "ring" (empty bullet) to be in blue, it is instead a mix of red and blue (red being the color of the active section).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=red,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{blue}\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}
\begin{document}
\section{Titre section}
\subsection{Titre sous-section}
\begin{frame}[t]{Titre planche} 
\begin{block}{Titre bloc}
\begin{itemize}
\item Un
\item Deux
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\section{Titre section}
\subsection{Titre sous-section}
\begin{frame}[t]{Titre planche} 
\begin{block}{Titre bloc}
\begin{itemize}
\item Un
\item Deux
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Won't changing `\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=red,bg=blue}` to `\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=blue}` produce what you want?

Comment: @erik Yes. But the other one will turn blue, too.

Comment: Perhaps the OP can clarify the desired outcome. Should the bullet of the active frame be red or blue? Should the bullet of the inactive frame be solid blue or just a blue ring?

Comment: @erik I want the bullets to be of the same color as the section titles.

Comment: @erik doesn't the big orange arrow and circle help clarify things?

Comment: @cfr No. The big orange arrow shows where the problem is, but the desired outcome wasn't clear.

Comment: @erik "On the top right of the slide, while I would like the bullet to be plain blue, it is instead a balanced mix of red and blue"

Comment: Yes, I read that. My question was basically this: do you want a blue ring or a filled blue circle to become a filled red circle when active? I see that @cfr's answer is what you were looking for, but restating exactly what you had in the question doesn't help to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you want something like this:

[image: blue other subsection unfilled circle]

This is covered on page 69 of the manual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=red,bg=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}[default][0]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}[default][0]
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{blue}\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}
\begin{document}
\section{Titre section}
\subsection{Titre sous-section}
\begin{frame}[t]{Titre planche}
  \begin{block}{Titre bloc}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Un
      \item Deux
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\section{Titre section}
\subsection{Titre sous-section}
\begin{frame}[t]{Titre planche}
  \begin{block}{Titre bloc}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Un
      \item Deux
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Don't you think it should be easier to control? I have to confess that I was not aware of the `\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}` command.

Comment: @pluton There may be a simpler way. The template is defined with an optional argument controlling the balance of `fg` to `bg` colour. However, this was easier than figuring out how to use that apparatus. But a Beamer expert would no doubt do better and simpler. I'd never heard of that command either. I just found it in Beamer's source code ;).

Comment: @pluton OK. I read the documentation instead. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It looks like your first solution better suits my needs.

Comment: @pluton Why? They should give identical output. They did for me.